# NodeJs for listing markers on Google Maps, on .net

Tags: .net, node.js

WE have a project that was developed on .net and part of that project was to read data from database and  display them as markers on google maps but now we need to implement that same functionality using NodeJs we are new on working with node, but also from what we were able to find on the internet  was more related with javascript, php or html sites , nothing specific 
with .net. If someone can at least direct us, how to approach to this problem,

Answer (score 0):

Install node package manager from npm website:

> https://npmjs.org/

and use the suitable page it's one command to install.

> npm install {package name }

More details: try the following steps found in this page:

> https://npmjs.org/package/googlemaps

Installing npm (node package manager)

> curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

Installing googlemaps

> npm install googlemaps